# How come a high capacitance TVS can be suitable for high speed applications?

Tags: esd

OnSemi published the following guide: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8231-D.PDF

There is a comparison chart which seems to be conflicting:

[image]

Shouldn't high capacitance be interpreted as unsuitable for high frequency applications?

Comment: Well it is listed as a "trade off" meaning maybe your high-speed application can tolerate it, maybe it can't.  It's up to the engineer to determine suitability.

Comment: @KyleB I don't understand, shouldn't it be labeled as suitable for low frequency applications compared to the configuration on the 3rd column ("low capacitance bidirectional")? Doesn't labeling both the 1st and 3rd configuration for high speed applications seems to be confusing to you? I mean, what is the point of the comparison chart then?

Comment: The chart tells you about alot more characteristics than just capacitance.   It's up to the designer to decide which set of characteristics is best for the application at hand.  There's no reason two configs can't both be "good for high speed"

Comment: The critical phrase is high capacitance ‘compared with a diode array’. Something like a SA5.0 TVS has a capacitance of around 1nF, so clearly this would be no good for USB whereas a SP3003 device quotes 0.65pF and is recommended for USB. Compared with a standard switching diode, 1N4148 which is specced at 4pF max. So, generally the average TVS diode does have a high capacitance, but not always.

Answer (score 2):

It just says high capacitance compared to diode array. So in relative terms. NUP2105L has 30pF max capacitance. Good for many purposes. And high speed is relative too. You would not use this on multi-gigabit lines, maybe on few megabit lines.

Answer (score 1):

Notice "High speed" in nearby cells, so these are distinct terms.

In the technical sense, high frequency (HF) is 3-30 MHz, though they might not mean it in that way here.  More broadly, "high frequency" might include SMPS applications, for example.

The key is probably something like: although the capacitance may be high, it's also high-quality, so it isn't necessarily a drain on the system.  There are applications where that capacitance is neutral or beneficial  Example: TVS across an RFID coil, the capacitance is balanced by coil inductance; it merely changes the tuning (which can be compensated for by design).  Counterexample: TVS across a switch (e.g. solenoid or motor driver), the TVS capacitance is always discharged by the switch, wasting its energy as heat.

It is true there are a lot of applications where increasing node capacitance degrades performance, so a low capacitance device is preferred -- or simply finding somewhere else to put it (example: suppressing extreme voltages in an SMPS by clamping the input/output, not the switch itself).

In contrast, "high speed" typically means digital logic signals that require attention to signal quality (transmission lines, impedance matching and termination, etc.).  Typically, LVDS, ECL, and some faster CMOS grades are involved.  Roughly speaking, bandwidth is limited by \$F_o = \frac{1}{2 \pi Z_o C}\$, and with Zo in the 100 Ω range, and required bandwidth of 100s to 1000s of MHz, tolerable capacitance is in the range of a few pF.